# How can I track usage of a Google Script deployed as public web app?

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script, statistics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing an application on Google Script platform which will be deployed as a web app later to general public. I want to track how people are using the script as Google Analytics does for a website. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific what do you mean by "how people are using the script".

One quick way to get stats for public requests to your script is to publish URL to your script via [Google URL Shortener](http://goo.gl). There you'll be able to see stats under the "Details".

---

But be aware, although shortened URLs are related to your Google Account, stats for those URLs are publicly available for everyone. You can check it yourself - pick any shortened URL (via Google Shortener) and insert it into the URL below, but without "http://" prefix:

```
http://goo.gl/#analytics/<Your-Short-URL-goes-here>/all_time
```

Answer (score 0):

It can now be done using the [Google Measurement API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).